# SQL row merging

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables from that I am retrieving following results after performing join operation.

[image: SQL table screenshot]

On the above result I want to do group by using FirstName, LastName and Email column and merge the row into the single row. After merging I should get other columns as well by using following scenarios.

1. Select the data which Created date is more recent.
2. After 1st scenario if it gives NULL, then select second highest Created date data and do this until we found non null result.
3. If all are rows having null then we can keep it as null.

For e.g. after merging I need the row like below. If you see I taken the recent created date rows which is 2nd rows, but gender and Address_1_State_Province are having null on recent created date rows so I taken the next recent created date row data value for this columns till I get non null value. Address_1_City, Address_1_Street_1, Address_1_State_Province are null because all rows are having null values.

[image: Final Result]

Current Query

```
 Select 
 case when u.firstname is null then ep.firstname 
 when u.insertDate > ep.INSERT_DATE then u.firstname else ep.firstname end 
 FirstName,
 case when u.lastname is null then ep.lastname 
 when u.insertDate > ep.INSERT_DATE then u.lastname else ep.lastname end 
 LastName,
 u.email as Email,
 u.gender as Gender,
 u.dob as Birthday,
 u.zip as Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code,
 u.city as Address_1_City,
 u.street as Address_1_Street_1,
 u.province as Address_1_State_Province,
 Convert(datetime,[dbo].[returnproperdate]((case when 
 isnull(u.insertDate,'')<>'' then [dbo].[returnmmddyyyy](insertDate) else 
 ep.INSERT_DATE end))) as Created,
 u.privacy as Privacy
 from [dbo].[Users] u
 join 
 [dbo].[EventsParticipated] ep on u.email=ep.EMAIL and u.brand=ep.BRAND
 where u.Email='18bonto@gmail.com'
```

Comment: What output do you currently get? What is wrong or insufficient about it? Please also format sample data as text tables using the SO editor, rather than including them as screenshots.

Comment: This looks like [Last non NULL](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle) to me

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (Select 
 case when u.firstname is null then ep.firstname 
 when u.insertDate > ep.INSERT_DATE then u.firstname else ep.firstname end 
 FirstName,
 case when u.lastname is null then ep.lastname 
 when u.insertDate > ep.INSERT_DATE then u.lastname else ep.lastname end 
 LastName,
 u.email as Email,
 u.gender as Gender,
 u.dob as Birthday,
 u.zip as Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code,
 u.city as Address_1_City,
 u.street as Address_1_Street_1,
 u.province as Address_1_State_Province,
 Convert(datetime,[dbo].[returnproperdate]((case when 
 isnull(u.insertDate,'')<>'' then [dbo].[returnmmddyyyy](insertDate) else 
 ep.INSERT_DATE end))) as Created,
 u.privacy as Privacy
 from [dbo].[Users] u
 join 
 [dbo].[EventsParticipated] ep on u.email=ep.EMAIL and u.brand=ep.BRAND
 where u.Email='18bonto@gmail.com'
 ),
 finalCTE as (select   FirstName, LastName, Email,
 (case when gender is null then  max(Gender)over (partition by firstname order by Created desc)end) Gender, 
 Birthday, (case when Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code is null then  max(Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code)over (partition by firstname order by Created desc)end) Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code, 
 (case when Address_1_City is null then  max(Address_1_City)over (partition by firstname order by Created desc)end) Address_1_City, 
 (case when Address_1_Street_1 is null then  max(Address_1_Street_1)over (partition by firstname order by Created desc)end) Address_1_Street_1, 
 (case when Address_1_State_Province is null then  max(Address_1_State_Province)over (partition by firstname order by Created desc)end) Address_1_State_Province, 
 Created ,Privacy,row_number()over(partition by firstname  order by Created desc) rn from cte)
 select FirstName, LastName, Email, Gender, Birthday, Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code, Address_1_City, Address_1_Street_1,
 Address_1_State_Province,  Created,Privacy from finalCTE where rn=1
```

New Query

```
       select FirstName, LastName, Email, Gender, Birthday, 
       Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code, Address_1_City, Address_1_Street_1,
       Address_1_State_Province,  Created,Privacy from
       (
       select  FirstName, LastName, Email,
       (case when gender is null then  max(Gender)over (partition by firstname order by Created desc)end) Gender, 
       Birthday, (case when Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code is null then  max(Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code)over (partition by firstname order by Created desc)end) Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code, 
       (case when Address_1_City is null then  max(Address_1_City)over (partition by firstname order by Created desc)end) Address_1_City, 
       (case when Address_1_Street_1 is null then  max(Address_1_Street_1)over (partition by firstname order by Created desc)end) Address_1_Street_1, 
       (case when Address_1_State_Province is null then  max(Address_1_State_Province)over (partition by firstname order by Created desc)end) Address_1_State_Province, 
       Created ,Privacy,row_number()over(partition by firstname  order by Created desc) rn 
       from [dbo].[JoinedResultUserandEvent])T
       where T.rn=1
```

Third Query:

```
       select FirstName, LastName, Email, Gender, Birthday, Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code, Address_1_City, Address_1_Street_1,
       Address_1_State_Province,  Created,Privacy from
       (
       select  FirstName, LastName, Email,
       (case when gender is null then  max(Gender)over (partition by firstname,lastname,email)end) Gender, 
       (case when Birthday is null then  max(Birthday)over (partition by firstname,lastname,email)end) Birthday, 
       (case when Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code is null then  max(Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code)over (partition by firstname,lastname,email)end) Address_1_ZIP_Postal_Code, 
       (case when Address_1_City is null then  max(Address_1_City)over (partition by firstname,lastname,email)end) Address_1_City, 
       (case when Address_1_Street_1 is null then  max(Address_1_Street_1)over (partition by firstname,lastname,email )end) Address_1_Street_1, 
       (case when Address_1_State_Province is null then  max(Address_1_State_Province)over (partition by firstname,lastname,email )end) Address_1_State_Province, 
       Created ,Privacy,row_number()over(partition by firstname,lastname,email  order by Created desc) rn 
       from [dbo].[JoinedResultUserandEvent])T
       where T.rn=1 and T.Email='18bonto@gmail.com'
```

Before Merge:
[image]

After Merge:
[image]

Comment: Thank for your help dale, sorry but i was added the wrong query, now corrected that can you check on that, because previous query gives only single row result and this new query gives 4 row result so i need to group by this

Comment: I have changed my answer. But without sample data I have no way to check it. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Kazi thanks for your response, Actually for simplifying query i stored the initial result into the new table ([dbo].[JoinedResultUserandEvent]) and on that your query is applied, can you check whether this is correct or not. The query is pasted on above

Comment: Without data it's difficult to judge a query but It seems perfect.

Comment: Please let me know if you face any more difficulties.

Comment: I made that change in the query means wherever you added the Partition by only on first name on there i updated to first name, last name and email. I made the another query please check 3rd Query section, however still I am not getting expected result. I am added the where clause and checked the record for one email id(18bonto@gmail.com). In that after merging wherever the partition by added for merging columns there i am getting null. You can check the images of before merge and after merge.

Comment: Is it possible to share input statement so that I can recrate the situation.

Comment: Kazi, Yes I am trying to share that by editing the post but it not allowing me to do that and it showing me suggested edit queue is full. Can you tell me how that i am able to share with you

Comment: You can add in my answer as you added the new query.

Comment: That's what i tried, but unable to edit the answers as its showed suggested edit queue is full, but now I am able to edit the answer Please check the answer.

Comment: I have removed order by clause from all max() window function. Please check it now.

Comment: Thanks Kazi this is resolved, now i am able to get exact result

Comment: That's really great to know. You did it. Best wishes.